How to evaluate the complex integral: $\oint_{\Gamma^+}\frac{1}{z\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-z)}\big)}dz$?

Evaluate the following complex integral
$$I = \oint_{\Gamma^+} \frac{1}{z\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2(1-z)}\big)}dz$$
where $\Gamma^+ =\{|z|=\sqrt 3\}$ oriented counterclockwise.


In this kind of exercises I struggle a bit since I'm not always sure what is the best way to approach contour integration. I've calculate singularities: $z_k = 1-\frac{1}{2k+1},k\in \Bbb Z$ so $z=1$ that is not an isolated singularity is inside $\Gamma^+$ and I cannot use residue theorem.

Edit From here follows a first idea that turns out to be not very effective I'll leave it there since maybe it could be used but I'm not really sure if I can make it work...

As is written I think that a possible way to proceed is by substitution $w = \frac{1}{1-z}$ so
$$I = \oint_{\Psi}\underbrace{ \frac{1}{w(w-1)\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{2}w\big)}}_{g(w)}dw$$
much nicer if able to compute accurately $\Psi$. Since we have a Möbius transformation I know circle gets mapped to circles or lines and the map is conformal.
 We have $\sqrt{3}  \to \frac{-1-\sqrt 3}{2},-\sqrt{3}  \to \frac{-1+\sqrt 3}{2},0 \to 1,$
from this I can deduce that real axe gets mapped to the real axe and since the map is conformal $\Psi = \big\{|w+\frac{1}{2} |= \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \big\}$ clockwise (I think...) and contains $z=0$ and $z=-1$. Since $z=0$ is a simple pole
$$\text{Res}_g(0) = \lim_{z\to 0}z \ g(z) = -1 $$
we have
$$I = -2\pi i \{ \text{Res}_g(0)+ \text{Res}_g(-1)\} $$


Thank you for your time!

I don't think $\Psi$ is calculated correctly because translation changes the modulus. I would use a parameterization $z(t)=3 e^{i t}$  and apply real variable methods. I did that and used Mathematica to compute the integral. Interestingly I get the value $2 \pi i$.

Actually I think it is naive to try to escape the singularities via transformation. I imagine wherever you go the singularities will come with you :)

@Medo I'm trying to evaluate precisely $\Phi$. By the way other than the transformation I'm afraid I don't know how could I proceed :(

@Medo If I'm not messing up with calculation I think substitution turn out to be a valuable option, what you think about that?

First observation: you have a singularity at $w=-1$  which is a zero of $\cos{(\pi w/2)}$, but this is beside the point: I don't agree with this method. I don't think one can change complex variables on a contour integral this way.

Try Taylor series expansion of $cosz$.

Parametrizing the curve at $z(t) = 3e^{it}$ for $-\pi < t < \pi$, we get $I = i \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2(1-e^{it})}\right) ~dt$.  Posting as comment instead of answer because I haven't figured out what to substitute from there.

@Dan I think the parametrization should be $z(t) = \sqrt 3 e^{it}$

@TurquoiseTilt: You are correct.  Sorry for my error.

Since $\Gamma^+$ encloses non isolated singularity $z=1$ is not possible to use residue theorem but we have another useful resource;

Suppose that $\exists R >0$ and $f$ is analytic on $\{z\in \Bbb C : |z| >0\}$. If $\Gamma$ is a circle which radius is greater than $R$ centered in zero and traversed once counterclockwise then
$$\int_\Gamma f= -2\pi i\ \text{Res}_f(\infty)$$

to evaluate $\text{Res}_f(\infty)$ we have
$$\text{Res}_f(\infty) = - \text{Res}_{F}(0)$$
where $F(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z)$. So we compute $F$
$$F(z) = \frac{1}{z\cos\big(\frac{\pi z}{2(z-1)}\big)}$$
in $z=0$ we have a simple pole so the residue is
$$\text{Res}_F(0) = \lim_{z\to0}(z \cdot F(z)) = 1$$
hence
$$\int_{\Gamma^+}f = 2\pi i$$
as seems to be verified in the comments above.

Actually this result I've posted is wrong... well partially since the radius of the circumference is $\sqrt{3}$ and not $3$ so the best way to proceed is notice that given $\Gamma^-$ (same circumference traversed clockwise)
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\Gamma^+} f = -\int_{\Gamma^-} f &= -2\pi i [\text{Res}_f(2) + \text{Res}_f(\infty)]\\
& = -2\pi i \bigg[\frac{1}{\pi}-1\bigg] = 2\pi i \bigg[-\frac{1}{\pi}+1\bigg]
\end{align*}$$
confirming the results numerically obtained with MATLAB of $\approx i4.28318530718$.

If we enlarge the circumference to have radius $3$ we get $2\pi i$ since the only residue is the one at infinity.
